# sudo password in terminal not accepted

Tags: command-line, password

Assuming my login password is the one being referred, I cannot type that, or in fact, anything when password is requested. I read through the answer to an earlier question on this problem and tried what was suggested. I even typed my password on a separate document, copied and then pasted it into terminal; nothing.

I understand that a password may not display when typed, but one assumes that when you press 'enter' all will be well. All I get is - 'Sorry, try again'!!!!!

Do I need a special password for terminal? If so, where do I register it?

P.S. I am fully able to type in the command line. So data entry doesn't seem to be the problem, from a keyboard point of view.

Sorry guys, new to Ubuntu and not very clued up on programming. Willing to learn, though.

Comment: do you get any error for `sudo -v`

Comment: How do you paste the password in the terminal? `Ctrl-Shift-V` ?

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using? What language? Try `echo "password" | sudo -S whoami` and add the output to your question. Does that work? Does it print `root`? Make sure that `password` is your actual password.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` uses your user's password, it is the same you enter when logging in.
You can try changing your password with `passwd`.

Comment: How can he log in and change the password if he has no password? And if he can log in, then he has a password.

Comment: He says in his question he has a password.